# Error al intentar Usar un método en bucle en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito repetir este código en un bucle:

```
private void LoadTask()

    {
        for (int Zero = 0; Zero >= Settings.Default.Counter; Zero++)
        {


            if (File.Exists("file.analy"))
            {
                XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reminders.Information));
                FileStream Read = new FileStream("file.analy", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                Reminders.Information Info = (Reminders.Information)XS.Deserialize(Read);
                //CreateTask
                //TaskPanel
                Panel TaskPanel = new Panel();
                TaskPanel.Size = new Size(500, 500);
                //Creating A New Control, This Will Be The Task Visual GUI
                //Task
                PictureBox Task = new PictureBox();
                Task.Size = new Size(357, 446);
                Task.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Task.Image = Reminders.Properties.Resources.Task2;
                Point P = new Point();
                int PosTop = 12;

                    Point TaskP = new Point();
                    TaskP.X = PosTop;
                    TaskP.Y = 1;
                    Task.Location = TaskP;
                    PosTop += 300;

                Task.Click += new EventHandler(Task_Click);
                //Setting Control Properties
                //TitleBox
                TextBox TitleBox = new TextBox();
                TitleBox.Name = "TitleBox" + VarCounter;
                TitleBox.Text = Info.Title1;
                Point TP = new Point();
                TP.X = Task.Location.X + 40;
                TP.Y = 45;
                TitleBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                TitleBox.Size = new Size(274, 45);
                TitleBox.Font = new Font("Helvetica LT Std", 27, FontStyle.Bold);
                TitleBox.Location = TP;
                //DatePicker
                DateTimePicker DatePicker = new DateTimePicker();
                DatePicker.Size = new Size(126, 20);
                DatePicker.Value = Info.Date3;
                Point DTP = new Point();
                DTP.X = TitleBox.Location.X + 1;
                DTP.Y = 115;
                DatePicker.Location = DTP;
                DatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
                //HourPicker
                DateTimePicker HourPicker = new DateTimePicker();
                Point HP = new Point();
                HourPicker.Value = Info.Hour4;
                HP.X = DTP.X + 144;
                HP.Y = DTP.Y;
                HourPicker.Size = new Size(126, 20);
                HourPicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
                HourPicker.Location = HP;
                //DescriptionBox
                TextBox DescriptionBox = new TextBox();
                DescriptionBox.Multiline = true;
                DescriptionBox.Size = new Size(275, 260);
                DescriptionBox.Text = Info.Description2;
                DescriptionBox.Font = new Font("Helvetica LT Std", 27, FontStyle.Regular);
                Point DP = new Point();
                DP.X = TitleBox.Location.X;
                DP.Y = TitleBox.Location.Y + 110;
                DescriptionBox.Location = DP;
                DescriptionBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                if (Now >= DatePicker.Value && Now >= HourPicker.Value)
                {
                    TitleBox.ForeColor = Color.Coral;
                    DescriptionBox.ForeColor = Color.Coral;
                }
                //BringToFront
                DescriptionBox.BringToFront();
                DescriptionBox.BringToFront();
                DatePicker.BringToFront();
                DatePicker.BringToFront();
                HourPicker.BringToFront();
                HourPicker.BringToFront();
                //Putting data into Task
                //Putting All Controls Into The Task Panel 
                TaskPanel.Controls.Add(TitleBox);
                TaskPanel.Controls.Add(DescriptionBox);
                TaskPanel.Controls.Add(DatePicker);
                TaskPanel.Controls.Add(HourPicker);
                TaskPanel.Controls.Add(Task);
                ReminderPanel.Controls.Add(TaskPanel);
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                //LoadTask
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que quiero que la salida de este código sea crear varios de estos controles, pero el problema es que no crea ni uno.

(Sin el bucle solo crea 1 y Settings.Default.Counter es = 2).
Además, en las líneas

```
if (File.Exists("file.analy"))
            {
                XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reminders.Information));
                FileStream Read = new FileStream("file.analy", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                Reminders.Information Info = (Reminders.Information)XS.Deserialize(Read);
```

Lee información de un archivo y la muestra, así que debería leer información de otro archivo y así.
Gracias por su atención.
**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Buen día, vengo a hacer una actualización, ya he actualizado el código  lo que me han sugerido, al ejecutarlo se queda en pausa unos 10 o 20 segundos, solo mostrando 2 descriptionbox(lo cual supongo que representa que se han logrado hacer 2 descriptionbox, luego aparece un breakpoint (No se porque, y menos como hacer uno) Y me muestra un error, exactamente en la línea 296 (TaskPanel.Controls.Add(Task);). El error dice lo siguiente “System.Argument.Exception : El parámetro no es válido”.

Comment: Ya depuraste tu código paso por paso a ver si de verdad ejecuta las líneas?

Comment: Varias veces...

Comment: Hola Link. Lo primero, deberías cambiar el nombre de la variable  que utilizas para recorrer el bucle, utiliza i por ejemplo que es lo más común (Zero puede ser una palabra reservada). ¿Cuanto vale Settings.Default.Corner antes de entrar al bucle?

Comment: Otra cosa, esto Zero >= Settings.Default.Counter debería ser así Zero <= Settings.Default.Counter (como he dicho antes habría que cambiar el nombre de Zero por otro)

Comment: No veo que añadas `TaskPanel` a los controles de la ventana: `this.Controls.Add(`TaskPanel`)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, Counter vale 2

Comment: +1 a lo de la variable "Zero", en primera acostumbrate a usar camelCase para variables y campos, deja la notación PascalCase para propiedades, metodos, clases, etc. Y "Zero" suena a que esa variable contiene eso, el valor cero, pero en realidad es un contador.

Comment: Luego, hay mucho código que recomiendo refactorizar, por ejemplo puedes crear el objeto Point y asignarle valores en una sola línea: "Task.Location = new Point { X = PosTop, Y = 1 };" en vez de 4 líneas es 1, y no solo ahorras código sino que también te facilita el depurar código.

Comment: Por último, supongo que "ReminderPanel" existe en el formulario. Prueba a colocar un breakpoint en la línea "backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();" y cuando el código se detenga en ese punto inspeccionas el contenido de "ReminderPanel.Controls" para ver que contiene.

Comment: He hecho una actualización a la pregunta, sería bueno que le echaran un vistazo